# Find the positive root of the equation $ce^{-c}-2(1-e^{-c})^2=0$

Tags: exponential-function, roots, transcendental-equations

> Can you help me find a root for $c$ in the equation below?
>   $$ce^{-c}-{10\over5}(1-e^{-c})^2=0$$

By expanding this I got,
$$ce^{-c}-2 + 4 e^{-c}-2e^{-2c}=0$$
now grouping,
$$(c+4)e^{-c}-2-2e^{-2c}=0 \tag{1} $$ 
Let $$ e^{-c} = x$$ then $$ c = -\log x$$ 
Substituting these values in (1),
$$x^2 + (\log x - 4) x +1 = 0$$

Now if I apply formula to find the root of quadratic equation, $(\log x -4)$ term is coming inside the square root and making it complex to find the root. Am I proceeding right? Is there any other way to find the root of this equation?

If I plot a graph for this the curve is cutting x axis at $0.49$, which is one of the root. How to arrive at this mathematically?

[image]?

Comment: Yes, we can. Did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: yes. but I did't get the result. Answer for C is 0.49. I don't know to arrive that

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE and thank you for your question! For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Then share your findings, maybe there is just a little errors somewhere that we will be able to spot. Without your input it is merely a "do-my-homework-for-me" question.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy can u give me ur email? I will send that as pdf?

Comment: **Hint:** Let $x=e^{-c}$, expand the parenthesis, then group the terms with regard to *x*.

Comment: It appears that the solution can't be written down in closed form.

Comment: You just need to solve $\cosh(c)=\frac c4+1$. This may not be solved with [Kepler equation solution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) methods due to the trivial $c=0$ solution.

Answer (score 0):

Working with $c$ and rearranging the equation, we look for the non-trivial zero of function
$$f(c)=2 e^{2 c}- (c+4)\,e^c+2$$for which
$$f'(c)= e^{ c}\, \left(4 e^c-c-5\right)\qquad \text{and}\qquad f''(c)=e^{ c}\, \left(8 e^c-c-6\right)$$

The first derivative cancels at
$$c_*=-5-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{4}{e^5}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. The second derivative test reveals that this is a minimum.

Making a series expansion around $c_*$

$$f(c)=f(c_*)+\frac 12 f'(c_*) (c-c_*)^2 + O((c-c_*)^3)$$ Then an *estimate*
$$c_0=c_*+\sqrt{-2\frac{f(c_*)}{f''(c_*)}}$$

Converted to decimal, this gives $c_0=0.516463$ while the solution, given by Newton method, is $c=0.490110$.

Now, expanding $f(c)$ as a series around $c=\frac 12$ and then series reversion
$$c=\frac{1}{2}+t+\frac{\left(13-16 \sqrt{e}\right) }{2 \left(8
   \sqrt{e}-11\right)}t^3+O\left(t^{4}\right)\qquad \text{with}\qquad t=\frac{\left(4-9 \sqrt{e}+4 e\right)+2 f(c) }{11 \sqrt{e}-8 e }$$ Since we want $f(c)=0$ then, numerically $c=0.490113$.